# How to set layout for all amp-img?

Tags: amp-html

I want all amp-img instances on a page to use layout="responsive".  Is there a way to do this without setting it on each of them?

The following does not work:

```
amp-img{
    layout: responsive;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be specified inside the tag itself for each image. Not sure what your application is, but if you're outputting a bunch of images on one page you could make use of an [amp-list](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-list/) and mustache tags to define the image url and dimensions if they're different for each image through a JSON file. Then you only have to do the amp-img tag once and let amp-list take care of looping out the images.

That's how I output all the images on [this page](https://www.craigattachments.com/attachment-inventory/) of the site I manage.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. They are images shown at different locations of an article, so I cannot use a list and template. I use ASP. Net MVC, so it is very easy to deal with a list of images with C# on an cshtml page.  I am AMPlifying this MVC website right now.

Comment: Not sure how useful this would be for your case, but you can use your language of choice (besides JavaScript obviously) to manipulate things and automate certain processes. Our website is built on WordPress so we use PHP to automate a few things as well as remove and add CSS to keep the site under the limit.